# Stuck while building multi-page sign-up form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, javascript-objects

I was trying to make a multi page form under that for there was a span which said if already user then sign up it was supposed to show other section of form where the user can sign up but instead it keep showing

> login.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: showLogin is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login.html:1:1)

Here's the login.html file and below this is JavaScript file which I was working on

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Login to Artify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/stylesheets/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/stylesheets/login.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <header class="main-header">
          <a href="/index.html" class="heading">Artify</a>
        </header>
      </nav>
      <main class="form-container">
        <h1 id="form-header"></h1>
        <form class="login-form">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Eg. JohnDoe" />
          </div>
          <button class="submit" id="loginBtn">Log In</button>
        </form>
        <form class="Signup-form" id="first-page">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="firstName">Enter First Name: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Eg. John" />
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label for="lastName">Enter Last Name: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Eg. Doe" />
          </div>
          <button class="submit" id="next">Next</button>
        </form>
        <form class="Signup-form" id="second-page">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="username">Enter a Username</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Eg. JohnDoe" />
          </div>
          <button class="submit" id="signup">Sign up</button>
        </form>
        <span class="footnote"></span>
      </main>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="../src/scripts/login.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS file

```
const header = document.querySelector("#form-header");
const footnote = document.querySelector(".footnote");

const loginForm = document.querySelector(".login-form");
const firstPage = document.querySelector("#first-page");
const secondPage = document.querySelector("#second-page");

function showFirstPage() {
  loginForm.style.display = "none";
  header.innerText = "Create Account";
  footnote.innerHTML = `Already a user? <button id="change-form" onclick="showLogin">Log In</button>`;
  firstPage.style.display = "block";
  secondPage.style.display = "none";
}

function showLogin() {
  header.innerText = "Welcome Back!";
  footnote.innerHTML = `Don't have Account? <button id="change-form" onclick="showFirstPage()">Create now</button>`;
  loginForm.style.display = "block";
  firstPage.style.display = "none";
  secondPage.style.display = "none";
}

window.addEventListener("load", showFirstPage);
```

I got stuck at a point where I can't find any already published online reference

Comment: A hint - take a look at how you're attaching `onclick` within your `showLogin` function, and then compare that to how you're attaching `onclick` inside the `showFirstPage` function.